# Duplicate symbol

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Could someone please help me understand `what the duplicate symbol is` ?
Regards
JZ

> duplicate symbol _dragView in:
>       /Users/johnzofrea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/I.C.E.-hhtrjcilahjtzdcnpruoskiftdrw/Build/Intermediates/I.C.E..build/Debug-iphonesimulator/I.C.E..build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ImageCropView.o
>       /Users/johnzofrea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/I.C.E.-hhtrjcilahjtzdcnpruoskiftdrw/Build/Intermediates/I.C.E..build/Debug-iphonesimulator/I.C.E..build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HealthInsuranceInfo.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Check in Build phases, that you aren't compiling twice the same file.

Search dragView in your project, you should see that you have twice a reference.

Comment: Thanks will check it out. Yeah I kinda of thought that but when I search Targets Build Phases the file does not even exist !! Ahhhhh !! lol

Comment: Also , this crash only happens in the simulator not on a device. ?

Comment: try "product -> clean" then when simulator is selected ?

Comment: Hi Lory, not sure what you mean-> 'then when simulator is selected ?'

Comment: Lory found it , it was a dup symbol in build , I had so many could not see it at firs.